# How to add a variable value with auto increment value in an insert query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert, sql-insert

I have a localhost and I want to do something I hope I can explain it.
I have a table named 'students' in a database named 'theway', there is a column named 's_class_id' its kind is auto increment , and in php I insert some values in this table. But I want to insert a variable+the auto increment in the column named 's_class_id'. 
For example : The variable's value is 'a', and the auto increment value is '5'. I want the value which be inserted in the 's_class_id' like this 'a5'.
Any help?

Comment: You can do that using PDO. But first you need insert record `a` after that you will have to update same row, and at that time pdo will give you lastInserId. You can use it for updating `s_class_id` `a5`.

Comment: @Mr.Developer I'm using mysqli for this time. Can I find a solution for this ?

Comment: I would like to recommend PDO Extension it will be also protect you from Sql Injection

Comment: PDO is in my plans. But I'm using mysqli in a project from many months and I can't convert to PDO right now.

Answer (score 0):

If it is auto-increment, the field should be an integer. Do not think that it is possible to change it to eg: 'a5'. You could run an update query searching for the s_class_id and update another string field to set it to be 'a5'.

Comment: I thought about that before adding this question. But I realized that I can find another solution more speedy than this. If I can't I will do this. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: Do not think that a number field that you autoincrement can be changed to a string like 'a5'.
Anyways, last insert ID as mentioned by @Mr.Developer can be found here with sample codes http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do that task by folowing method,

First you need to insert record into `theway` table. After record insertion `mysqli_insert_id($con)` will return last inserted id. Then you need to update that row by using last inserted id.

```
// Insert Record
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO theway  (s_class_id) VALUES ('a')");
// Getting last inserted id
$lastInsertID =  mysqli_insert_id($con); 
$updatedValue = 'a'.$lastInsertID;
// Update same row with last inserted ida
$SameRowUpdate = "UPDATE theway SET s_class_id='".$updatedValue."' WHERE id=".$lastInsertID;
if (mysqli_query($conn, $SameRowUpdate )) {
    echo "Record addedd successfully";
}
```

Comment: Mmmm , that means I can't do anything non that solution. Mainly I did that after adding my question. But I realized that I can find another solution more speedy than this. If I can't I will do this. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @AmeerAhmed If the answer is helpful then accept and vote up for future reference.